# Dynamically change the template url in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a SPA in which data is stored in a JSON file. The JSON file also contains the link to the pages including ID. Whenever the user searches for an ID, the content of the page corresponding to that id should be loaded. How to do it?

Comment: DId you tried anything already ?

Answer (score 0):

Your search implementation should be separate, perhaps with a directive. There is no good answer to that, unless you have something to work with already.

However, the dynamic template loading can be achieved with a method that allows you to read URL parameters, such as ID, and re-direct accordingly. One of these methods is $location, whereas the best one for your case is **$routeParams**.

Here is an example:

```
const app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/some_path/:ID', {
    templateUrl: 'templates.html',
    controller: 'templateCtrl'
  });
}
```

(*For more advanced control, switch ngRoute to ui-router library and adjust accordingly*)

With this once your URL is in a form: `www.example.com/some_path/10`, it will re-direct you to that page with a $routeParams.ID value of "10".

In your template controller you can then use $routeParams to load your JSON file and fill in the $scope values of the page accordingly.

```
app.controller("templateCtrl", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  var id = $routeParams.ID;
  $http.get('myFile.json').
  then((res) => {
    // match your ID and load the data
    let data = res.data;
    let model;
    for (let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
      if (data[i].id == id){
        model = data[i].content;
        break;
      }
    }
    $scope.model = model;
  });
});
```

If your want to wait until the data is loaded, before you display your page content, then use **resolve** in the config with appropriate factories / services that load your JSON files.